# Request-based Sticky Session configuration with Spring Cloud LoadBalancer

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

I have the following configuration for request-based sticky session using Spring Cloud LoadBalancer

```
spring:
  cloud:
    discovery.client.simple.instances:
      say-hello:
        - instanceId: say-hello1
          uri: http://localhost:8080
        - instanceId: say-hello2
          uri: http://localhost:8081

    loadbalancer:
      configurations: request-based-sticky-session
      sticky-session:
        add-service-instance-cookie: true

server.port:9090
```

the following call:

```sh
$ http :9090/hi 'Cookie:sc-lb-instance-id=say-hello1'
```

should go only to the `say-hello1` instance based on the [Request-based Sticky Session for LoadBalancer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#request-based-sticky-session-for-loadbalancer) but instead is using round robin load balancing.

What do I miss here?

Here is the source code to try it: https://github.com/altfatterz/client-side-loadbalancing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things to consider here:

1. In the sample, the cookie has to be passed on to the actual load-balanced request, for example like so:

   ```
   @GetMapping("/hi")
   public String hi(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "Mary") String name) {
    logger.info("Accessing /hi endpoint");
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Cookie", "sc-lb-instance-id=say-hello1");

    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> greeting = restTemplate.exchange("http://say-hello/greeting", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class, new HashMap<>());
    return greeting + " " + name;
   }
   ```
2. This feature is only supported for WebClient-backed load-balancing. It was not properly documented. I have documented it [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/commit/2e0db8e21ede62d0c5602e6e2da4264224aae2bc).
   I have also created [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/971) for adding the non-reactive implementation, however, the decision to implement it will be dependant on larger community interest.

Comment: Thanks Olga! Is there a way to check what ServiceInstance a RestTemplate based load balancer client chose for a request?

Comment: We log that. Also we provide `LoadBalancerLifecycle` interface (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#loadbalancer-lifecycle) -  you can provide your own logic and add that information to your final response.