# Request Based Sticky session with Spring Cloud Loadbalancer not working as expected

Tags: load-balancing, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, sticky-session

I am using Spring reactor and WebClient for load balance purposes. I want to use the Request-based Sticky Session for LoadBalancer as follows:

Have service A that can invoke REST end points on service B or service C. Both B and C can have multiple instances of them running at a given time.

1. I want to use the standard round robin balancer for service B.
2. I want to use the request-based sticky session balancer for service C.

This is my code in the service A (that can invokes both service B and service C) through the WebClient. But it always ends up with round robin algorithm for service C. Can someone please
help me to figure out what I am doing wrong or missed to do? I referred to the below link

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#request-based-sticky-session-for-loadbalancer

and also looked into the below SO

[Request-based Sticky Session configuration with Spring Cloud LoadBalancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68026243/request-based-sticky-session-configuration-with-spring-cloud-loadbalancer)

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @LoadBalanced
  @Qualifier("loadBalancedWebClientBuilder")
  WebClient.Builder builder() {
    return WebClient.builder();
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("webClientBuilder")
  WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
    return builder.build();
  }
```

}

application.yml (I am not very sure where the sticky-session definition should be added; i.e. **service A** or **service C** and hence repeated the below in both the services)

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service-A
  cloud:
    loadbalancer:
      ribbon:
        enabled: 'false'
      sticky-session:
        instanceIdCookieName: sc-lb-instance-id
        addServiceInstanceCookie: true
```

Code in the **service A** to **invoke service C with request based sticky session**. I have a different file that does the same for service B (without the sticky session but uses the same WebClient Builder).
I know the service instance id that I want the WebClient to use to route the call.

```
@Component
public class ServiceCClient {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("loadBalancedWebClientBuilder")
  private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

  public Mono<Void> triggerServiceCEndPoint(String paramA, String svcInstanceId) {
        return webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://service-C").build()
                .post().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/v1/example/end/point")
                        .queryParam("param-a",paramA).build())
                .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                    httpHeaders.set("sc-lb-instance-id",svcInstanceId);
                })
                .cookie("sc-lb-instance-id", svcInstanceId)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Void.class);
  }
```

}